# Which dense matrices are hard to invert?

Tags: linear-solver, iterative-method, error-estimation

Suppose I'm solving $Ax=b$ for dense $m\times d$ matrix $A$. For which $A$ is this hard to do?

More concretely, is there any work on estimating the error after $k$ steps of iterative solver, $k\le d$, for some specific solvers, based on properties of $A$? For random isotropic vector $x$ and large $d$, a useful property proved [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/532117/distribution-of-langle-x2-a-rangle-where-x-is-is-a-random-direction) is that

$$T^k x \approx c \operatorname{Tr}(T^k)$$

Hence this comes down to understanding how fast $\operatorname{Tr}(T^k)$ decays where $T$ is the iteration matrix of corresponding solver. Which properties of $A$ result in $\operatorname{Tr}(T^d)$ being large?

Classical approach formulates difficulty in terms of condition number $\kappa(A)$, but this comes into play after many steps, ie $k>d^2$. When $d$ is huge, we can only afford $k=O(d)$ steps. For instance, [modern language model](https://scontent-sjc3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t39.8562-6/333078981_693988129081760_4712707815225756708_n.pdf?_nc_cat=108&ccb=1-7&_nc_sid=ad8a9d&_nc_ohc=8TSHY74yfqYAX8HgsDl&_nc_ht=scontent-sjc3-1.xx&oh=00_AfBPuhFa5iF1v9ARmCu67O7HD9Vp7qPGY77YFEsT2geEeg&oe=6407B8A2) might have $d\approx$10B and be trained for 1B steps. A linear analogue of this problem is to solve $Ax=b$ where $A$ is a dense $10B\times200B$ matrix, in less time than it takes to read the matrix $A$.

For "single step gradient descent", you can show that an expression involving second/third moments of the matrix determine the difficulty of approximate inversion for gradient descent using $k=1$, but I feel like I'm reinventing the wheel here

$$\frac{\text{loss}_1}{\text{loss}_0}\approx1-\frac{\operatorname{Tr}(H^2)^2}{\operatorname{Tr}(H^3)\operatorname{Tr}H}$$

where $H=A^TA$

Comment: This question is limited to an iterative solver, right?

Comment: Yes, because I don't believe there exist non-iterative solvers which can work on dense large matrices with $d$ in the billions

Comment: In practice, I agree. But since I am coming from the world of fast direct methods (with ~20M unknowns dense matrix solved using "compressed matrix" techniques arising from Maxwell's equations) I had a theoretical question in my mind for my purposes.

Comment: One relevant reference I have is [this post by Higham](https://nhigham.com/2019/05/07/numerical-algorithms-for-high-performance-computational-science-highlights/) which contains an overview of talks on exascale from a certain conference. I encountered questions along this line of thinking in the context of _exascale numerical linear algebra_.  With [this presentation from Eric Carson on iterative linear algebra in exascale era](https://nickhigham.files.wordpress.com/2019/05/talk10-carson.pdf) being the closest.